# Where can I download the offline install for visual studio 2015 express?

Tags: download, visual-studio-2015, offline, iso, visual-studio-express

Where can I download the offline install  for visual studio 2015 express?

On the official website im only able to find the web installation.

For security reasons, the computers in my company do not have internet access. I would like to find the ISO installation or some offline installation.

Obs. **I can not use the community version** for legal reasons.

Comment: Not off topic at all, this is a very useful question for those having build dependency issues with github cloned repos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first you have to download vs2015 express web version (wdexpress_full_ENU.exe : 209 kb)

then run following command in your command prompt:

```
wdexpress_full_ENU.exe /layout
```

final downloaded folder size is about 9.16 GB

EDIT: [Visual Studio 2017 express](http://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_WDExpress.exe) changed [offline installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)

EDIT: [Visual Studio 2019](https://developerinsider.co/download-visual-studio-2019-web-installer-iso-community-professional-enterprise/#downloadvisualstudio2019iso) community :

```
vs_community.exe --layout C:\vs2019 --lang en-US
```

Comment: For some reason `wdexpress_full_ENU_<numbers>.exe` (209KB) gives me errors on win2016. It tries to download `wdexpress_full.exe` (2.8MB) that lives here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615464 , but fails for some reason. Fetching `wdexpress_full.exe` from that link and using `/layout dir` with it worked fine for me.

Comment: @alexkasko thanks for that link: it works fine.

Comment: try this link: https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/8/9/E89E0AA3-EBC8-46DD-823B-9CECD1F95051/wdexpress_full_ENU.exe

Answer (score 0):

Get it here, its on the same page the web instaler is:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409

**Note** there is no express version of VS 2015, they renamed it to "Community"

Comment: sorry, but there is express editions for Vs 2015 at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx. They call our sight to community edition, however there is the online installation for each express version below it.

Comment: Express Edition is called now "Desktop".

Comment: @panako Express edition for web still exists, desktop is different

Comment: ^ not anymore..